# node-pre-gyp and grpc problem while trying to run project Angular 6

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to run my project but this error comes everytime and now I'm stuck.

I tried to delete node_modules and reinstall it, I tried also to run cache clean.
I copied the grpc file from another project and paste it on mine but still not working.

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.20.0 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\YAZANMU\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-19T11_48_11_067Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you not able to install the dependencies because of this error? I've faced something similar in the past but it was just a warning and didn't have much impact on running my app or building it.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I can't install, run, build or do anything because of this error.

Comment: Is this the only error that you're getting? No other error or warning related to any other package or node_module?